# zf2 and doctrine entity relation

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am new in zf2. I need your help.

Suppose I have 5 tables such as : table 1, table 2, table 3, table 4, table 5.

And one relation table in which primary keys of all the tables are kept as foreign keys.
The structure of relation table is like this:
    id - table1_id - table2_id - table3_id - table4_id - table5_id

My problem is when I am fetching data using
`$this->getEntityManager()->find('Application\Entity\Relationtable', id);`
It is returning all data.

Is there any other way to fetch only two or three table data using same relation table.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could write the query you need using [dql](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) queries in your `RelationTableRepository`.

Something like

```
SELECT r.table1, r.table2 FROM \Application\Entity\RelationTable
```